# find worktime proportion of downtime

Tags: sql-server-2008

With reference to managing downtime of a supported system, i would like to be able to report from my call handling database how much of the downtime fell within the supported hours. Supported hours being 9-5 weekdays only. So if a system goes down at midday on Friday and is back up at midday the following Tuesday, i need to record 16 hours of downtime:
5 hours on friday 12-5
8 hours on Monday
3 hours on Tuesday 9-12.

Ideally i would also like to exclude bank holidays but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly assume the report takes 2 parameters @t1 DATETIME, @t2 DATETIME where @t1, @t2 are the start and end times of the period you want to report over.

I would create a table containing all support time periods e.g. CREATE TABLE SupportTime (StartSupport DATETIME, EndSupport DATETIME) for all continuous support periods. (This could contain a lot of rows if spanning several years but shouldn't be too difficult to generate).

Lets assume there is a similar table CREATE TABLE DownTime (StartDownTime DATETIME, EndDownTime DATETIME) which contains all the downtime periods.

The report query needed should then look like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN StartSupport < @t1 THEN @t1 ELSE StartSupport END AS StartSupport, 
        CASE WHEN EndSupport > @t2 THEN @t2 ELSE EndSupport END AS EndSupport
        FROM SupportTime
        WHERE @t1 <= EndSupport
        AND @t2 >= StartSupport)

SELECT
    SUM(
       DATEDIFF (mi,
       CASE WHEN dt.StartDownTime < CTE.StartSupport THEN CTE.StartSupport ELSE dt.StartDownTime END,
       CASE WHEN dt.EndDownTime > CTE.EndSupport THEN CTE.EndSupport ELSE dt.EndDownTime)
   ) As DownTimeMinutes, -- Total of down time during support time (mins)
FROM DownTime AS dt
INNER JOIN CTE ON (CTE.StartSupport <= dt.EndDownTime
                   AND CTE.EndSupport >= dt.StartDownTime)

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, CTE.StartSupport, CTE.EndSupport)) AS SupportTimeMins
```

I'll try to explain what's going on - the virtual CTE table contains all the relevant support periods between the reporting dates with StartSupport or EndSupport adjusted if the start report time or end report time falls within the support period. The JOIN of CTE with DownTime table sums the difference between StartDownTime and EndDownTime for all relevant records (StartDownTime and EndDownTime adjusted again if they fall outside StartSupportTime or EndSupport).